# How to count all relationships in a database?

Tags: sql-server, schema

I am developing a web application, which stores data in a Microsoft SQL Server database. My project manager has to deliver a report to non-tecnhical higher-ups, and thinks that it will read impressive if we include the sentence "Our database has X tables, connected by Y relationships".

I just counted the tables by hand in the treeview of Management Studio. But how do I get a count of all relationships in the database? I'd prefer something quicker than generating the schema and ticking off each connector by hand.

Comment: if you are going count the tables in DB then query would be **SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179987.aspx for the foreign keys

Comment: [`sys.foreign_keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) could be used as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' --counts all tables
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.referential_constraints --counts all FK relationships
```

Comment: A little bit of an explanation as to what this will show, will help other users.

Comment: Ooops, others are right, add the WHERE table_type = 'base table' to get the tables only or else views are also counted.

Comment: Maybe I used a wrong term? I'm not sure this is counting what I want to count. This query delivers 60 referential constraints for 56 tables, and intuitively this feels like too small a number. And when I look at the visual representation in Management studio, the relationships are not listed under Constraints.

Comment: @RumiP. then you may want to elaborate on your specification :)

Comment: @blobbles please edit your answer with the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Sorry, yes, done now :-)

Comment: @RumiP. Hmmmm, very strange. Does:

SELECT *
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type_desc = 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT'

give you the same number?

Comment: @blobbles yes, it delivers the same 60 relationships, and I only have 53 base tables, I had used your first version without the WHERE to get 56. Now that I think of it, maybe all the hard places where I had to place multiple relationships in the database are much more salient and so my intuition says there should be more relationships, but in truth many of the tables are simple lookup tables which have just one relationship to their main entity, so the number is probably correct and my intuition wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going count the tables in DB then query would be

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'
```